# Re-enable selection on Firefox dialog

Tags: firefox

I checked the 'Don't ask me again' option at some point, and now these dialogues don't appear any more, but I actually want them to show. How do I enable them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Firefox and type `about:config` to the address bar. Navigate to value **dom.max_script_run_time**, right-click on it and select **Reset**